# How should we semantically version add-on packages?

Tags: versioning

I have read the [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) , however, it does not mention how should we deal with add-on packages.

For add-on package, I mean the package that extend the main package, but not necessary come with the main package. The package naming convention is usually `<main>-<addon>`, e.g. `maven-war-plugin`.

Assume the main page is `pkg` and has version 1.5, and we have add-on package named as `pkg-dothis`. What I want to achieve is the version of add-on package  should indicate that:

1. It is compatible with `pkg` 1.5
2. It is capable of showing the new features (It has its own minor version)
3. It is capable of showing the bug fix version (It has its own bug fix version)

Is 1.5.<minor>.<bugfix> good enough?

**Edit** : Rolf Rander suggests I should not use the term "sub package", so I assume "add-on" is less misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of sub-package is not completely clear. If package X is dependent on packages A, B and C, which is it a sub-package of? I think you will be better of by not using the term sub-package. Trying to express dependency management in your version numbers will probably lead to problems later. What if `pkg-dothis` is compatible with several versions of `pkg`?

Comment: Say, if I were to develop a maven plugin, the naming convention is maven-<something>-plugin. It cannot live without maven, thus maven is the "main" package. Mmm, perhaps "add-on" is better.

And yes, `pkg-dothis` may be compatible with older `pkg`, but lets say that `pkg-dothis-1.5.???`  does use the functionality from `pkg-1.5`.

Comment: Maven is a good example, take a look at how maven plugins are versioned. For example the [site](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-site-plugin-3.3/)-plugin is developed close to maven itself. It is in version 3.3 but works with maven 2.2.1 or newer. The maven-plugin for [jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) is completely separate, the latest release is 2.12.1, but this works with maven 2 or 3. I would advice against putting to much semantics in to a single value like the version number.

Comment: or take a look at logback, which is split in separate modules which might be labeled "sub-package" or "module", but they synchronize version numbers so all logback-modules have the same version.

Comment: Thanks for providing valuable points of consideration. 
However, if I want to decouple the version from the main package, I don't need to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what community expected.

maven community does not seem to care too much about matching main package version. So you can just ignore the main package version.

KDE communities, on the other hand, add-on applications are expected to match at least first two version numbers [1](https://community.kde.org/Applications/Versioning). In these communities, if the add-on update style is more or less like the main package, that is, whenever the main package is out, you modify accordingly and use the new feature from the main package, then you can simply use KDE versioning. That is, either match main package or use the patch level (the 3rd number) for your own version.

If new feature updates may squeeze in between main package's minor updates, then <main-major>.<main-minor>.<addon-minor>.<addon-bugfix> seems like the reasonable way.